# Is it possible to fill the gap without JavaScript after one element moved out with transform?

Tags: css, flexbox

The problem is demonstrated here: https://codepen.io/PengXiao/pen/NWwKpgB
[image]
As you can see in the above picture, `message1` and `participant1` was covering the whole width of `message-container`. `participant1` is moved to the right for 50% with translateX and created a gap (shown as orange).

My questions is whether `message1` can grow to fill that gap. I understand that `transform` will not impact the current layout. So we don't have to use `flex` and `transform`. I have just used flex for demo. However, we have the following constraints:

1. content for participant and message is dynamic;
2. participant must move to the right for 50%;
3. width of 'message-container' is fixed, but it does not consider the dynamic width of participant.

The final result I am trying to achieve is like this:
[image]

Yes, it is for the renderer of ZenUML :)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

changes made using the `transform` property are merely visual, You can use negative margin to move the element.

```css
.message-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}

.message {
  height: 40px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: green;
}

.participant {
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: -40px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-container">
  <div class="message">message1</div>
  <div class="participant">participant1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: width of `participant` is dynamic, so I cannot use `margin-right: -40px`, because I don't know the real width of participant (constraint #1).

Comment: `margin-right: -40px` was an example, And yes that's the issue, i can't think of anything else that would influence DOM elements other than margin, i don't think you can do this with just CSS, then again there might be some elaborate hacks. wait for other answers.